# Nivo slider add box-shadow to image

Tags: wordpress, css, nivo-slider

Hi I have implemented the jquery Nivo slider plugin into my custom wordpress theme.

I added the following code to add my custom style to the slider:

```
.nivoSlider {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    border: 1px solid rgba(36, 38, 38, 1);
}
```

Unfortunaly the box-shadow doesnt show only the border does. I tried to adjust the z-index and such but wasnt able to get a good result.

Anyone with an idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Could you link an example of your HTML markup? The container of the nivoslider may generate some issue for the box-shadow.

Comment: I added the HTML markup and PHP code in comments: http://jsfiddle.net/qbPCE/